# How to better manage versions in Sitecore Page Editor

Tags: sitecore

The way that Page Editor handles versions has been causing issues for in one of our Sitecore solutions for a client. I've posted about them here:

- [Sitecore instance showing incorrect workflow state in Page Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268668/)
- [Expected usage of Page Editor's Experience date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334874/)

I didn't get much response on those and so far I've surmised that this is just how Sitecore works. This is less than ideal for our instance, as when publishing restrictions are set, authors don't know which version they're editing which is causing various issues for them.

I'd like to implement a solution(s) to improve the experience provide the following functionality:

- Something in the Experience tab that shows the number of the version being viewed.
- A button on the Experience tab that resets the Date to the default (this is not simply setting the date to the current date/time, but resetting it to act as it did before a date was manually set).
- A custom button in Content Editor which allows an author to open a specific version in Page Editor...set the date automatically when it opens, I guess.

An any one give me some clues on how much of this is possible and where to start?

Thanks.

Comment: In general, a page is made of multiple components (renderings) each with their own datasource. Each datasource will have its own version count so which would be displayed in the tab?

Comment: We're using a "dynamic component" architecture, partly described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554973/ Any global components on the page are managed as global items outside of the page, so we don't care what version of those are shown in this context. For components which are created solely as content on that page (like Rich Textboxes), we have code that keeps the pub restrictions and workflow in sync between these and their page.

Answer (score 0):

For the first bullet "Something in the Experience tab that shows the number of the version being viewed", you can add version item in Core database.

1. Move to "Core" DB in Desktop Mode
2. Navigate to "/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Experience/"
3. Create "Versions" item like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbaUs.jpg
4. Create "Compare" item under "Versions" like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKDU5.jpg
5. The result like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/f477A.jpg

The content author can see which version they are using and they can also compare with previous versions.

Comment: Thanks Jay. So the click: item:compareversions is already built in and you're just referencing it? Do you know if there's a reference listing all these actions?

Comment: Acutally, I don't know. What I did is that copying version information from "content editor" node to "Page Editor". If you figure out the how they get all version information in "Content Editor", it will be easy to embed into "Page Editor"

Comment: @Scott: Check your Commands.config file. It will have a whole bunch of commands that Sitecore can trigger. However, your best bet overall is to find something that works in Sitecore similar to what you want to do, find it's definition in the Core database, and start creating something similar to that.